# Replace a regex pattern in a string with another regex pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Is there a way to replace a regex pattern in a string with another regex pattern? I tried this but it didn't work as intended:

```
s = 'This is a test. There are two tests'
re.sub(r'\btest(s)??\b', "<b><font color='blue'>\btest(s)??\b</font></b>", s)
```

The output was:

```
"This is a <b><font color='blue'>\x08test(s)??\x08</font></b>. There are two <b><font color='blue'>\x08test(s)??\x08</font></b>"
```

Instead of the desired result of enclosing the keyword `test` and `tests` with html tags:

```
"This is a <b><font color='blue'>\test</font></b>. There are two <b><font color='blue'>tests</font></b>"
```

And if there was a workaround, how could I apply that to a text column in a dataframe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in result you want to put element which it found in original text then you have to put regex in `()` (to catch it) and later use `\1` to put this element in result.

```
re.sub(r'(\btest(s)??\b)', r"<b><font color='blue'>\1</font></b>", s)
```

BTW: it needs also prefix `r` in result to treat `\` as normal char.

Result:

```
"This is a <b><font color='blue'>test</font></b>. There are two <b><font color='blue'>tests</font></b>"
```

---

If you will use more `()` then every `()` will catch separated elements and every element will have own number `\1`, `\2`, etc.

For example

```
re.sub(r'(.*) (.*)', r'\2 \1', 'first second')
```

gives:

```
'second first'
```

In example it catchs also `(s)` and it has number `\2`

Comment: Thank you. I learned something new about grouping `()` in regex. I couldn't follow the last sentence though. What did you meant by `s` in "*it catches also `(s)` and it has number `\2`*"?

Comment: `()` in `(s)??` is also grouping so when string  has `tests` then `\1` has `tests` and `\2` has `s`, And when string has `test` then `\1` has `test` and `\2` is empty. Run `re.sub(r'(\btest(s)??\b)', r'>\1< >\2<', 'test tests')` and you get `>test< >< >tests< >s<'`
`

Comment: Your clarification really helped me understand more about regex. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to replace.

```
import re


def replacer(match):
    return f"<b><font color='blue'>{match[0]}</font></b>"


s = 'This is a test. There are two tests'
ss = re.sub(r'\btest(s)??\b', replacer, s)
print(ss)
```

```
This is a <b><font color='blue'>test</font></b>. There are two <b><font color='blue'>tests</font></b>
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to decide yours or Furas' method should be accepted as the answer. I really liked your approach as it's easier to understand and can be readily applied to a column of a dataframe. On the other hand, Furas addressed the criteria in the OP of *replacing regex pattern with another regex pattern*. Thank you for your help though.